# PHP hide/show images with pagnation

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

Result I want to achieve
[image: Something i want to achieve]

PS: Please ignore the error in the center.

Current
[image: Added pagination]

Just update the codes and manage to solve the **019** problem and loop through all the image once. However, still unable to display 3 image on a single page.

Previously manage to display what i want with the help of css {display}
 and JavaScript show/hide function, but not sure how to do with php.

```
$productArr = ["ac" => ["001" => ["dimension"=>"H: 85 W: 67 D: 72",  "price"=>850.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "002" => ["dimension"=>"H: -- W: -- D: --",  "price"=>860.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "003" => ["dimension"=>"H: 95 W: 71 D: 90",  "price"=>890.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "004" => ["dimension"=>"H: 78 W: 68 D: 78",  "price"=>740.00 , "images"=>4], 
                    "005" => ["dimension"=>"H: 102 W: 69 D: 90", "price"=>890.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "006" => ["dimension"=>"H: 89 W: 80 D: 86",  "price"=>1280.00, "images"=>7], 
                    "007" => ["dimension"=>"H: 78 W: 66 D: 66",  "price"=>680.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "008" => ["dimension"=>"H: 80 W: 78 D: 74",  "price"=>800.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "009" => ["dimension"=>"H: 94 W: 64 D: 88",  "price"=>790.00 , "images"=>5], 
                    "010" => ["dimension"=>"H: 83 W: 68 D: 72",  "price"=>850.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "011" => ["dimension"=>"H: 70 W: 66 D: 77",  "price"=>860.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "012" => ["dimension"=>"H: 88 W: 84 D: 88",  "price"=>1280.00, "images"=>7], 
                    "013" => ["dimension"=>"H: 80 W: 70 D: 84",  "price"=>860.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "014" => ["dimension"=>"H: 82 W: 68 D: 80",  "price"=>780.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "015" => ["dimension"=>"H: 82 W: 72 D: 78",  "price"=>890.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "016" => ["dimension"=>"H: 75 W: 59 D: 47",  "price"=>780.00 , "images"=>7], 
                    "017" => ["dimension"=>"H: 90 W: 77 D: 83",  "price"=>1280.00, "images"=>7], 
                    "018" => ["dimension"=>"H: -- W: -- D: --",  "price"=>680.00 , "images"=>5], 
                    "020" => ["dimension"=>"H: 74 W: 63 D: 89",  "price"=>860.00 , "images"=>4]]

$catCode = $_GET['cat'];

$arr=[];
foreach ($productArr[$catCode] as $imgNumber  => $productDetail) {
    array_push($arr,$imgNumber);
    $imgNumber = $arr;
 // index[18] change to 20
}
       echo"<div align='center'>  
        <ul class='pagination'>";
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]) / 3 + 1; $i++) {
            echo"<li><a href='http://localhost/ca1/collectionPage.php?cat={$catCode}&page={$i}'> {$i}</a></li>
         ";
        }
        echo"<li><a href='http://localhost/ca1/collectionSummary.php?cat={$catCode}'>view all</a></li>";
        echo"</ul>
        </div>";

    for($i=0; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]); $i++){   
        echo  "<div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='thumbnail'>
                    <img class='img-responsive image_size' src='images/$catCode/row_{$catCode}{$arr[$i]}_m0.jpg'>
                    <div class='caption'>
                        <p align='center'><b>Model No.Row-{$upperCatCode}-{$arr[$i]}</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> ";
```

}

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and where you are struggling?

Comment: I think the question is about showing/hiding the images via PHP

Comment: @StefanDochow sorry for my poor english. Yes, it is about showing/hiding the images via PHP with pagination.

Comment: @Vykintas Thank you for answering, i have just added pagination, do you have any idea how to link the hide/show image with pagination?

Comment: If you have pagination, you can use my sample (below) and show images by number. For example If you show 6 images on page - you can count $from = ($page*6)-6; and $to=$page*6; Of course array must contain images you want to show on current "library" only. Got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit which images to show by indexes, but then you will need to send values **FROM** and **TO** to php script and add in loop something like this:

```
if(($i>$FROM)||($i<=$TO))
   {
      // Show the image
   }
```

If you will use a loop you have shown.